# Is bifurcation analysis automatized?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm in the process of defining a thesis in mathematics, more closely defined dynamical systems, and bifurcation diagrams played a big role in the dynamical system courses I've taken. But of all the articles I'm reading this seem to have been completely automatized by the use of for instance XPPAUT: http://www.math.pitt.edu/~bard/xpp/xpp.html

Is this true?

Comment: No, it's not fully automated. Roughly speaking, AUTO usage consists of many steps that pick known regime in a system (equilibrium or limit cycle, for example), continue it with respect to a parameter and watch what happens in between the starting and the final points. During the numerical continuation it detects typical bifurcations of this regime along the path in parameter space and tells you about them. These points at the path are your "seeds" for future bifurcation curves, but you have to say manually that you want AUTO to plot a bifurcation curve through a particular point.

Comment: Clearly not, the present automation corresponds to 0% of the theory (even if you disregard the nonlocal theory, which corresponds to 100% of the whole theory).

Comment: @JohnB Can you explain the opinion about 0% of the theory?

Comment: It is not an opinion, it is an obvious fact. Probably you know about the difficulty of studying nonlocal bifurcations. Many, and it is simple to formulate them, would give PhD thesis.

Comment: @JohnB Okay, can you explain the obvious fact then?

Comment: Ah, and please don't take me wrong. I find your first comment above a perfect description of the problems in actual implementations. I am talking instead about the big picture. Would we even dream to do something in line for nonlocal bifurctions?

Comment: @JohnB I mainly disagree with point on 0% theory. Of course, the complete analysis is beyond the scope not only of any software, but even maybe of human understanding. And that's where I totally agree with you: no software can do EVERYTHING for us. What such software can do is detecting local codimension-1 and 2 bifurcations, and this is pretty solidly based on theory, not just an heurestics. And sometimes in applications this skeleton of simple bifurcations can explain a lot. P.S. What is p3 and p4?

Comment: Agreed! Have a look at http://mat.uab.cat/~artes/p4/p4.htm

Comment: @JohnB That's interesting, thanks for a reference! It's pretty strange that [this list](https://dsweb.siam.org/Software) doesn't mention this software...